# Can't test the javascript regex correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi all I have the following Regx that can't be accepted on the JavaScript

```
if ($(caller).attr('value').toString().search('/(?=\D*\d\D*\d).{8,15}/g') == -1)
```

where

```
$(caller).attr('value').toString() = "fdsddfsd45"
```

it returns to me **-1**

also I'm try to test it from pattern

```
  if (!pattern.test($(caller).attr('value'))) {
```

where

```
pattern = /^(?=D*dD*d).{8,15}$/
```

it returns to me **false**

```
$(caller).attr('value').toString() = "fdsddfsd45"
```

when I tried to test it through desktop application called RegExr this string "fdsddfsd45" match the expression (?=\D*\d\D*\d).{8,15} is this JavaScript bug I don't know ?

Comment: If I may, what are you checking there? it looks like you're testing if the string is at least 8 characters long, and has two digits. The regex seems wrong, or at least overly complex. Can you describe what you're trying to do? 
One last note - you didn't say exactly what you're doing, but you may have forgotten the start and end anchors: `^...$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript the regex should either be a string or a regex literal. In your case, this should do it:

```
.search(/(?=\D*\d\D*\d).{8,15}/) == -1
```

Note that I removed the single quotes. I've also remove the `/g` flag - since you are searching for any match, you don't need it.

For completeness, while it less useful, you could have written the regex as a string, but you'd have to escape all backslashes, or JavaScript will parse `\d` as `d` before it even reaches the regex. In this case, you don't need the slashes (unlike PHP, for example, which uses both):

```
s.search('(?=\\D*\\d\\D*\\d).{8,15}')
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/ubuce3

Answer (score -1):

```
"fdsddfsd45".search(/^(?=\D*\d\D*\d).{8,15}$/g)
```

will return 0, be careful the "'" character!

and

```
/^(?=\D*\d\D*\d).{8,15}$/.test("fdsddfsd45")
```

will return true!